# jQuery Find Input Text Elements several levels

Tags: jquery, dom

first at all thanks for reading.

I wrote a code that suppose to search any input type text inside many  the idea is search if each element inside of the  contains a text, if it's then the tr will be .show() if any of the elements inside of the tr contains the text the tr will be .hide().
But i cant get the value of the input, maybe some silly mistake.
So the structure could be:

```
   <tr>
    <td><div><div><input type="text" value="hello world" /></div></div><td>
    <td><div><input type="text" value="hello world" /></div><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="tutu" /><td>
    <td><span><input type="text" value="orl" /></span><td>
    </tr>

/* renglones is every <tr> */
$.each( renglones, function() {
        var inputs = $(this).find('input [type=text]').find('input');
        console.info(inputs);
        $(inputs).each(function() {
            console.info($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Comment: You are looking for an input that is a child of an input that is a child of an input. Should just be `var inputs = $(this).find('input[type=text]');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the [:text selector](https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)

```
renglones.each(function () {//assuming renglones is a jQuery object
    var $inputs = $(this).find('input:text');
    $inputs.each(function () {
        console.info($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Arun P Johny

Final code:

```
$.each( renglones, function() {
        var $inputs = $(this).find('input:text');
        var encontrado = false;
        $inputs.each(function () {
            if($(this).val().indexOf(texto.toLowerCase()) != -1 || $(this).val().indexOf(texto.toUpperCase()) != -1){
                encontrado = true;
            }
        });
        if(encontrado){
            $(this).show('200');
        }
        else{
            $(this).hide('200');
        }
    });
```